# Rolling weekly/ monthly active users on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking for rolling weekly/ monthly active users on bigquery. I've tried the previous posts, but using CROSS JOIN exceeds bigQuery's limits.

I use the following as a very basic form of the required output, but I would need a similar output for everyday and not just on month-end dates.

```
SELECT 
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(id) AS uniqueInstalls,
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(date, '%Y-%m') AS calendarYM
FROM Analytics.EventsTable2 
GROUP BY calendarYM
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

> I would need a similar output for everyday

Try below for/with BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH calendar AS (
  SELECT day 
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
    (SELECT MIN(DATE) FROM `Analytics.EventsTable2`), 
    (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM `Analytics.EventsTable2`), 
    INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ) AS day
)
SELECT 
  c.day AS day,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS uniqueInstalls
FROM calendar AS c
JOIN `Analytics.EventsTable2` AS t
ON t.date BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(c.day, MONTH) AND c.day
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

You can test / play above with dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, DATE("2017-04-01") AS DATE UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE("2017-04-02") UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE("2017-04-02") UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE("2017-04-03") UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE("2017-04-04") UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE("2017-04-04") UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE("2017-04-04") UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, DATE("2017-04-05") UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE("2017-03-02") UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE("2017-03-02") UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE("2017-03-03") UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE("2017-03-04") UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE("2017-03-04") UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE("2017-03-04") UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, DATE("2017-03-05") 
),
calendar AS (
  SELECT day 
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
    (SELECT MIN(DATE) FROM yourTable), 
    (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM yourTable), 
    INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ) AS day
)
SELECT 
  c.day AS day,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS uniqueInstalls
FROM calendar AS c
JOIN yourTable AS t
ON t.date BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(c.day, MONTH) AND c.day
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

> This first query returns the following error Error: No matching signature for function GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY

Below is the version for TIMESTAMP in input data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH calendar AS (
  SELECT day 
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
    (SELECT MIN(DATE(date)) FROM `Analytics.EventsTable2`), 
    (SELECT MAX(DATE(date)) FROM `Analytics.EventsTable2`), 
    INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ) AS day
)
SELECT 
  c.day AS day,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS uniqueInstalls
FROM calendar AS c
JOIN `Analytics.EventsTable2` AS t
ON DATE(t.date) BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(c.day, MONTH) AND c.day
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, however, I don't have standard SQL and BigQuery is not accepting the query you offered. Let me know if you have an alternate query. Your help is deeply appreciated :)

Comment: @StevePereira - BigQuery has two sql dialects: legacy and standard. So if you do "have" BigQuery - you do "have" both dialects including standard one. Just run above queries as is (including first line #standardSQL) in your Web UI - try and let me know result!

Comment: I appreciate the lesson! Here's the output: 
Row | day | uniqueInstalls |
------------------------------
1 2017-03-02 2  
2 2017-03-03 2  
3 2017-03-04 3  
4 2017-03-05 4  
5 2017-03-06 4  
6 2017-03-07 4  
7 2017-03-08 4  
8 2017-03-09 4  
9 2017-03-10 4  
10 2017-03-11 4  
11 2017-03-12 4  
12 2017-03-13 4  
13 2017-03-14 4  
14 2017-03-15 4  
15 2017-03-16 4  
16 2017-03-17 4  
17 2017-03-18 4  
18 2017-03-19 4  
19 2017-03-20 4  
20 2017-03-21 4

Comment: @StevePereira - so output is as expected - you should just adopt this t your specific use case/data :o) technically - the first query should be good start for you! second query is just to see how it works with dummy example/data. does it make sense now?

Comment: Sorry, still too advanced for me. I understand the structure of your query, but I don't know what the syntax would be to input the Date_Array.

Comment: @StevePereira - you do not need to input date_array - it is handled for you by query! The only what you need as an input is your table! Isn't it - Analytics.EventsTable2?

Comment: I did. The second query gave me the same result when the query runs with 'yourTable' or `Analytics.EventsTable2`. This first query returns the following error Error: No matching signature for function GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY for argument types: TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, INT64, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE, DATE, INTERVAL [INT64] [DATE_TIME_PART]) at [4:15]

Comment: @StevePereira - what exactly the datatype of your date field? in example it is a DATE. So we will need to adjust it to whatever datatype is in your case. So what it is? Ideally you should apply a little more efforts by your own rather than asking each and every small piece!

Comment: @StevePereira - see my last update in answer. added casting of `timestamp`s to `date`s

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, sorry. I'm new to stackoverflow and I have no formal training in SQL. You are correct DATE is a TIMESTAMP. Your second query worked, but the output does not seem to provide a continuous rolling count of unique active IDs over X amount of days.

Comment: @StevePereira - I have already added version for TIMESTAMP - please try!

Comment: It seems to start the count at the beginning of the month instead of a rolling 30 day period.

Comment: @StevePereira - oh - great! at least we have a progress now and it works. to make it 30 days rolling just replace `BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(c.day, MONTH) AND c.day` with `BETWEEN DATE_SUB(c.day, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND c.day`

Comment: WOW! You cracked my mind wide open! I see what you did in order to be able to execute the query, but my syntax knowledge of SQL isn't yet developed enough to have made it work. Many Thanks! If you know of any good online SQL course please let me know.